# Azure ACS 2 Custom Domain

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, appfabric, wif, accesscontrolservice

I'm trying to set up Authentication in an ASP.NET MVC App and if so using the Azure Access Control Service (ACS) (v2 May 2011 release). I've got this working with the default setup. However there is a usability problem here.

When I authenticate using my Google Account... Google says..`mydomain.accesscontrol.windows.net` is requesting access to the account. This can be confusing to end users as they are expecting to use `login.mydomain.com`.

I've pointed a DNS CNAME record from `login.mydomain.com` to `mydomain.accesscontrol.windows.net` and uploaded an X.509 cert for `login.mydomain.com` via the Access Control Services Control Panel. however I get a server error when I try to access https://login.mydomain.com as the certificate sent to the browser is for `*.accesscontrol.windows.net` . NB. I can't see what the error is as it is on an Azure ACS server.

has anyone here managed to successfully set up a custom domain for ACS and can advise on how to do it? It seems it's possible for the Roles and Storage accounts, but I can't find any documentation on this for the AppFabric group of services.

Comment: We will try the same in about one week. Good question!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, I don't think this is supported today in ACS.

Comment: Have you tried setting this up using ADFS that federates TO ACS?

Comment: Yes. It works :-) The trust chain looks like App -> ADFS -> ACS -> LiveId/Google/Yahoo!/OpenID/ADFS